# Query.execute is not a function

Tags: node.js, aerospike

When I am trying to execute query using query.execute() than it shows it is not a function. I was already tried it and it was working before last 3 months. Is it removed from new aerospike node client update?

And if yes than which are alternative options. Can I filter query without secondary index?

Comment: Answered here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/query-execute-is-not-a-function/4799/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Query#foreach`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Query.html#foreach). `Query#execute` was marked deprecated in the v2.0 client release and has been removed in v3.0. Please refer to the full [list of API changes in v3](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/master/docs/api-changes.md#version-300).